# Cannot get CNAME on DNS to work correctly

Tags: domain-name-system, cname-record, nslookup

The domain in question is www.photoparata.com.  I am hosting it at GoDaddy.com and have it set to be a CNAME to www.miltonstreet.com.  When I go to http://centralops.net/co, they have it correct, as does the system when I go in and look at GoDaddy's system.

The problem is that when I try using NSLOOKUP on Windows 7 and connect to server 10.0.80.11, it just times out.  When I try to surf to www.photoparata.com from either my laptop on my home network or from my tablet on LTE, but take me to a page that says things are not setup correctly.

Any thoughts on what the issue might be?

Comment: Your DNS setup is fine, Apache is misconfigured

Answer (score 3):

The DNS is fine.  The issue is the web server at 198.143.164.133, which now needs to be configured to resolve the virtual domain www.photoparata.com.

The deal is this: A CNAME only guarantees that the same IP will resolve for two different names.  A CNAME does **not** make www.photoparata.com have the same content when connecting to the IP with miltonstreet.com.

The reason is because a web browser sends information like this when hitting the web server for photoparata/miltonstreet:

```
GET / HTTP/1.0
Host: www.miltonstreet.com
```

or

```
GET / HTTP/1.0
Host: www.photoparata.com
```

The reason being: IPv4 addresses do not grow on trees, so we have to give many different domains, each with their own content, the same IP

The web server for miltonstreet needs to have a virtual host for photoparata set up pointing to miltonstreet's content.

Answer (score 0):

```
www.photoparata.com.    3600    IN      CNAME   www.miltonstreet.com.
www.miltonstreet.com.   14400   IN      CNAME   miltonstreet.com.
miltonstreet.com.       14400   IN      A       198.143.164.133
```

The record has been set correctly.
The things might be:

1. DNS propagation
2. DNS cache

in both cases reboot you PC/router and wait a bit for DNS propagation